# How to pass the result of CONCAT() function to my UDF in Pig?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I want to pass the result of a CONCAT() to my User Defined Function in Pig. Currently, I have a script with the following line, however the script gives me an error when i run it.

```
B = FOREACH A GENERATE myjar.MyUDF(CONCAT(r1,r2));
```

Is this possible in Pig?

If not, is there a way to pass two parameters to a Pig UDF?

Comment: What errors is it giving you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Pig you can pass multiple parameters to UDF.

You can pass like this .

```
A = LOAD 'file.txt' USING PigStorage(',') AS (id:int,f_name:chararray,l_name:chararray);

B = FOREACH A Generate id,name,MYUDF(CONCAT(f_name,l_name),lname,f_name,'hi');
```

Also remember you can the pass the output of one UDF to another UDF

```
C = FOREACH B Generate UDF1(UDF2('hi'));
```